# How to initialize all members of an array to the same value in Swift?

Tags: arrays, initialization, swift

I have a large array in Swift. I want to initialize all members to the same value (i.e. it could be zero or some other value). What would be the best approach?

Comment: Create the array, loop through all of the elements and set each one, just like you would in any other programming language.

Comment: `var a = Array(count:100, repeatedValue:0)` is exactly the answer to this valid question.

Comment: @Rod, I'll try that. If the question is reopened you can post it as an answer.

Comment: Looping is at least an order of magnitude slower than using vector math.

Answer (score 205, accepted):

Actually, it's quite simple with Swift. As mentioned in the [Apple's doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID112), you can initialize an array with the same repeated value like this:

With **old Swift version**:

```
var threeDoubles = [Double](count: 3, repeatedValue: 0.0)
```

Since **Swift 3.0**:

```
var threeDoubles = [Double](repeating: 0.0, count: 3)
```

which would give:

```
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

Comment: It seems that in Swift3 it changed to `var threeDoubles = [Double]( repeating: 0.0, count: 3 )`

Comment: I have discovered this is really sloooooooow, a 16MB array takes seconds to clear this way.  In C , `memset(p, 0, 16*1024*1024)` is practically instantaneous.

Comment: @wcochran  Did you discover a better way to do this?

Comment: @javadba Nope. Still surprised there is no efficient mechanism to do this in Swift when the hardware can do this fast. Maybe its worth investigating the source.

Answer (score 37):

This would be an answer in Swift 3:

```
var threeDoubles = [Double]( repeating: 0.0, count: 3 )
```

Comment: Autosuggest states [Double](repeatElement(3.22, count: 5)), still explicitly typing (repeating, count) seems to be valid