# how to change the button title on click inside a tableview cell in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I got  a tableview cell inside that i have image view , label and a ui button , i need to change the button title text and background colour on click . But when i try to do button from multiple cell is having the same effect . Please do help me !

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell1", for: indexPath) as! subTableViewCell

    cell.catNameLabel.text = categoryNameArray[indexPath.row]

    cell.descLabel.text = descriptionArray[indexPath.row]

    cell.freqLabel.text = frequency[indexPath.row] + " at " + frequencyTime[indexPath.row]

    let url = "http://wiinnova.com/tenly/image/category_image/\(categoryImageArray[indexPath.row])"

    cell.img.imageFromServerURL(urlString: url)
    cell.button.tag = indexPath.row
    return cell 
}
```

Comment: reload your tableview when button clicked

Comment: i reload but no change .. same issue

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to assign `button.tag` at all, Here is the way:

First of all add `target` to your button. Like:

```
cell.button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(handleRegister(_:)), for: .touchUpInside).
```

Then:

```
//This function will be called for each button click. 

func handleRegister(sender: UIButton) {

let buttonPosition = sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: YOUR_TABLE_VIEW)
let indexPath: IndexPath? = YOUR_TABLE_VIEW.indexPathForRow(at: buttonPosition)

let cell = YOUR_TABLE_VIEW.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath)

//Now change the text and background colour
cell.button.setTitle("Button Title",for: .normal)
cell.button.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

   //...
}
```

To keep the track of your changed button background and title you will need an array as **@Tofaani Kaanudo**'s answer has suggested.

Comment: I have tried this but at the same time a button in someother row is having the same affect

Comment: Can you please update your question with that code you have tried?

Comment: It's will not work when tableView Scroll Up-Down because cell will be reusable.

Comment: Yes, Sorry for that i need to get the cell here using `converPoint` function. See the updated answer

Comment: yes when i Scroll Up-Down the cell is reusing ..so what i can to do to avoid it .. can i use tableview.reload() and where i can use it

Comment: @TofaaniKaanudo you have a nice way, But we can even avoid using `button.tag` if you want. Check my updated answer

Comment: @AnuragSharma - Yes but what will be happened when we scroll tableView and will be called **cellForRowAtIndexPath** method ? Button title and backedGround color will be reset again as normal so your updated effect will be gone. That's why we must need to use Array for handle updated effect.

Comment: @TofaaniKaanudo Yes, you are right for that we need an array to keep the track of selected/Unselected buttons :)

Answer (score 3):

First of all you should take one `Array` for manage clicked/changed `UIButton` for `reusableCell` otherwise if you scroll your tableView Up-Down then It will be remove effect

I'm giving my logic.

1) Take one mutable Array name is `temArray` *(Size equal to your tableView's Row)* and it has **0** value for each index. [you can do it by easy repeat value **0**.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24001936/how-to-initialize-all-members-of-an-array-to-the-same-value-in-swift)

2) in you `cellForRowAtIndexPath` datasource method check

```
if temArray[indexPath.row] == 0 {
   /// Write code for default UIButton - That has normal behavior means not changed title and no set background color
}
else {
  /// Write code for What you want to keep UIButton title and background color
}

cell.yourButtonObject.tag = indexPath.row
cell.yourButtonObject.addTarget(self, action:#selector(handleButtonClicked(_:)), for: .touchUpInside).
```

3) And add `handleButtonClicked` method and change `temArray` value

```
func handleButtonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let myIndexPath = NSIndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0)
        let cell = tblViewPref.cellForRow(at: myIndexPath as IndexPath)
        if temArray[sender.tag] == 0 {
        /// You can access your button by
        // cell.myButton..... change here text and background color
        // And change "temArray"

        temArray[sender.tag] = 1
       }
       else {

           /// You can access your button by
          // cell.myButton..... change here text and background color
          // And change "temArray"

         // SET DEFULT BUTTON TITLE AND BACKGROUND COLOR

         temArray[sender.tag] = 0
       }
    }
```

So when you scroll your table Up-down `temArray` will be managed by it's value at `indexPath` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` Datasource method.

Comment: what is to written in step 2 ie in if case and else case

Comment: @ShafeerPuthalan - temArray[indexPath.row] == 0 means you haven't clicked on button so make it as default title with default color and in the **else part** write same code for button that you wrote in **handleButtonClicked** method.

Comment: what about when we click the button again and set the button with default title and default color

Comment: Glad to help you accept my answer so any other developer that have same issue that will be use this code.

Comment: @ShafeerPuthalan you should accept the answer of Tofaani Kaanudo if it really helped you!

Answer (score 0):

Set the title and the background color properties of the button in tableview's `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` delegate

```
cell.button.setTitle("title", for: .normal)
cell.button.backgroundColor = .darkGray
```

Comment: All the button is changing i want to alter the only button that is clicked

Comment: Well, you have to check your button's tag, change the properties if it matches